# Web Api Project Fails to build with Visual Studio Team Services (was TFS Online)

Tags: tfs, build, continuous-integration, azure-devops

I have a project inside a solution and Visual Studio Team Services is setup to do continuous build.

The test project that includes the Web API project builds fine and even includes the artifacts from the web api project, but when I look at the drop folder from artifacts view it doesn't have a sub folder for the website.

This is done with a new default Visual Studio Build definition with bone stock settings. (no amount of playing around works either)

(I'd put in a screen shot but literally just create a new build definition as choose visual studio and continuous integration and click ok, and that's exactly what this is.)

The log file for the build step doesn't show that it even tries to build the csproj for the web api project and just skips right to the Tests project. (and no errors in the log either)

Going to configuration manager for that configuration (and all configurations) and the project in question is set to build.

It builds properly in that configuration with that project just fine.
It publishes from Visual Studio with that project just fine.

Any ideas why it won't build the project?

Comment: Did you set the project to build?  Its really tough to help without any screenshots or errors.  Anything would help at this point.

Comment: As noted, all projects including this one are set to build. There is no screen shots because it's dead default and there is absolutely nothing in the log file other than the absence of any logging for the building of the project.

Comment: What is the Configuration set to on the build?  Debug/Release, Any CPU, etc.

Comment: Any CPU and custom one called beta which is also what's set in build under TFS variables.

Comment: Are you sure the project has the custom configuration defined?  I have seen this behavior when I forgot to add the custom configuration to the project.

Comment: Yes. It definitely has it. The list of projects under the build configuration is showing it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104305/discussion-between-chief7-and-james-hancock).

Answer (score 4):

According to the information you provided, you are using a default build definition for Visual Studio CI without any other settings. This definition does not generate the web app publish files.

Try adding following MSBuild Arguments in "Visual Studio Build" step and then queue a new build:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:outdir=$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)
```

**Update:**
Since you want to deploy the website by Azure Deploy from Release Management, you can just upload the deployment packages to drop. To do this, change the MSBuild Arguments to following:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"
```

And then you can go to Release Managament, in the "Azure Web App Deployment" step, set "Web Deploy Package" to "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\**\ProjectName.zip".

Comment: So this generates a folder in /drop/_PublishedWebsites/<projectName>_Package. (This is the zip etc.)

It also creates one without the underscore that has all of the lose files.

The issue then becomes getting the release to deploy to azure. I have the Azure Deploy step set to by using the ... so I didn't make any mistakes:

$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\<Build Definition Name>\drop\_PublishedWebsites\<Project Name>_Package

But when I do that I get:

No files were found to deploy with search pattern C:\a\c647c4ef4\<Build Defintiion>\drop\_PublishedWebsites\<Project Name>_Package

Comment: It says that it downloaded a ton of files though in the previous step of the release. What am I missing?

Comment: Well that got a little further now it's actually trying to deploy but I get: Website with given name XXX already exists.  Of course it does, that's the point, it should be updating the site that's already there!  I trust you're aware that the documentation is horrible and this should all just automatically work without any messing with command lines right?

Comment: And BTW, it doesn't update a list from Azure of sites and hitting the refresh button does nothing, the drop down is still empty even though it clearly can connect to Azure and even if it couldn't, it should throw an error telling you that it can't connect to Azure.

Comment: @JamesHancock This may caused by a known issue on Azure Powershell. Check this link: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1743281/build-vnext-azure-website-deploy-error-conflict-website-with-given-name-sitename-already-exists and try the workarounds in it.

Comment: Well that's just bizzare but it worked!  Still don't get a list of sites in the UI for the azure deploy but whatever, it deployed properly!  Is there anything I have to do with this same process to get this to work with 2 dotnet core web sites? Or if I hold my tongue in the right way like this will it work?

Comment: @JamesHancock To show your sites list in the UI, you need to select the "Web App Location" first. Set it to the location of your Azure Web Site and then click "Refresh" button of "Web App Name". The web sites in that location should be listed.